# .net localization - throw exception in hebrew on englisch operating system

Tags: c#, .net, validation, localization

I have an application that is translated into hebrew besides english and german.

To check the user input, i created a Validation rule that throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if the value exceeds it's limits.

```cs
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
  double validationValue = 0;
  validationValue = double.Parse(value.ToString());

  if(validationValue < Min)
  {
    ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex = new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    return new ValidationResult(false, ex.Message);
  }
  else if(validationValue > Max)
  {
    ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex = new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    return new ValidationResult(false, ex.Message);
  }

  return new ValidationResult(true, null); 
 }
```

The validation is working. 
However, if i set the application language to hebrew by using `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` I get an english exception. Setting the language to german or english, I get the correct exception message.
The operating system is Windows 7 english.

- Does the text of the exception depend on the installed languages of the OS?
- Can I resolve the problem by installing the hebrew Language pack (only for Win 7 Enterprise/Ultimate Edition)?

I tried to set the region to Israel, but I cannot install the hebrew LP on my current test environment.

I found threads where people said that exceptions should not be translated. I could use my internal localization service to throw my specific exception with the translated text. But if there is a chance, I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Why does it matter what language the exception text is in, as the type is always the same? Unless you're showing the exception message directly to the user?

Comment: Have you tried installing .Net Framework Language Pack?

Comment: You should not return the exception message to the client, the exceptions are not translated to all languages. You should use some sort of translation mechanisem for example here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26469667/custom-validation-message-language-specific

Comment: Well the exception message is shown directly to the user. I find it disturbing if most of the application is shwon in the selected language and at some points a different language shows up.

Comment: @Pikoh Thanks for the hint with the .Net Language Pack. I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: @ZivWeissman Thank you for the link. I will try this sample

Answer (score 1):

The .Net language pack is working. Although i refactored my validation rule. A custom message is now returned if the value is out of the range.

- I can include the minimum and maximum of the possible value.
- Future translations are not dependent on installed .NET language packs.